# Request to MX server from a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, email-validation

**Context**

Our solution send emailing campaign, and some email provider makes temporary blacklist because we used inexistant email addresses (they may be created/imported by any user)

**Solution**

I try to implement a email checker based on https://www.codexworld.com/verify-email-address-check-if-real-exists-domain-php/

**Problem**

From my local computer, this script works (when my IP is not temporary blacklisted) but from my Docker Container `stream_socket_client` or even `telnet` always times out.

As I see, MX servers always time out non verified requester but how can I make it work from my docker container?
I've no specific docker configuration for the port 25.

Thank you

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# Base docker-compose file to run required services: Adminer, MySQL, and Redis
version: '3.7'

services:

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    cap_add: [ SYS_NICE ] # https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/303
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci', '--lower_case_table_names=1']

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    expose:
      - "6379"

  redisinsight:
    image: redislabs/redisinsight
    ports:
      - "8081:8001"

  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    volumes:
        - ./../../../backend/infra/etc/nginx/dev.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
        - "80:80"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: container/dev/backend.dockerfile
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - {...}
    depends_on:
      - database

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: container/dev/frontend.dockerfile
    expose:
      - "3000"
    volumes:
      - {...}
    tty: true # required to keep yarn running (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61050994)

volumes:
  # Contains the database's data
  db_data: {}
# Base docker-compose file to run required services: Adminer, MySQL, and Redis
version: '3.7'

services:

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    cap_add: [ SYS_NICE ] # https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/303
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci', '--lower_case_table_names=1']

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    expose:
      - "6379"

  redisinsight:
    image: redislabs/redisinsight
    ports:
      - "8081:8001"

  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    volumes:
        - ./../../../backend/infra/etc/nginx/dev.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
        - "80:80"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: container/dev/backend.dockerfile
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - {...}
    depends_on:
      - database

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: container/dev/frontend.dockerfile
    expose:
      - "3000"
    volumes:
      - {...}
    tty: true # required to keep yarn running (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61050994)

volumes:
  # Contains the database's data
  db_data: {}
```

backend.dockerfile is an ubuntu with git, mysql-client, php

Comment: Check the logs, and when you do not have them create logging for you SMTP session.   (The default in the code you linked to is: `$Debug = false`)

Comment: Logs only contains 
`2022-04-04 08:13:41 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com:Connection timed out`
Same for each mx server

Comment: How is your docker configured?  Does it have a firewall?  You need to check why connection to the external server fails.

Comment: Thank you for your help
I add my docker-compose.yml to the initial post.
The odd thing is that on it, telnet with most of ports works, but not 25.
For instance : `telnet rpc.acronis.com 443` works /  `telnet www.google.com 80` works / `telnet ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com 25` time out

Comment: Go and have a ☕with your network administrator.    (see: https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver/issues/598 )

Comment: I will dig further with him, thank you